# How is the unigram tokenization using EM algorithm?

Tags: natural-language, expectation-maximization

I intuitively understand what is happening in the unigram tokenizer and I think I also understand the EM algorithm if I can figure out the formulation in which I understand it i.e. What is the latent variable and what is the data given (basically, the graphical formulation).

The unigram tokenizer is [as follows](https://stanford-cs324.github.io/winter2022/lectures/modeling/#unigram-model-sentencepiece):
[image]

[another good link for the unigram tokenizer](https://youtu.be/TGZfZVuF9Yc)

Can you help me reconcile the unigram model with the EM algorithm? How is the unigram model using the EM algorithm

1. What is the latent variable here?
2. What is the E step? I understand the E step as finding the expected log-likelihood of the data where the expectation is taken under the posterior. The expectation is taken under the posterior because it maximizes the likelihood and thus EM algorithm is also seen as a maximization maximization algorithm
3. What is the M step. I understand the M step as the maximization (in the parameter space) of the expected log-likelihood found in the E-step. What are the parameters here that we are optimizing upon to maximize the expected log-likelihood found in the E-step?

Comment: Not for nothing, but the answer is stated in [the paper linked in those course notes](https://aclanthology.org/P18-1007/).